# Visual Studio 2012, C#, Compiler Options

Tags: c#, компилятор

Привет. Как скомпилировать проект C# с оптимизацией по размеру, и как скомпилировать с оптимизацией по скорости? Спасибо

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Среди [ключей компилятора C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6s2x2bzy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) есть лишь один, относящийся к оптимизации: [`/optimize`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t0hfscdc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Таким образом, вы не можете управлять оптимизацией, вы можете лишь включить или выключить её.

Это относится не только к Visual Studio 2012, но и к версиям с Visual Studio .NET 2003 вплоть до текущей Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: Спасибо. Такой вопрос. При включеном /optimize, заметил, что размер кода значительно меньше, чем при отключеном. Значит ли это, что при отключеном ключе /optimize происходит оптимизация по скорости?

Comment: @thejadefalcon: Думаю, что при отключенном `/optimize` оптимизация не производится вообще. Уменьшение размера кода — побочные эффект оптимизации. Кроме всего прочего, бОльшая часть оптимизации реально происходит на этапе JIT, которым, кажется, вовсе невозможно управлять (по крайней мере я не знаю, как).